# PropType is defined but prop is never used

Tags: reactjs, jsx, lint

```
const propTypes = {
  prop1: PropTypes.string,
  prop2: PropTypes.string,
  prop3: PropTypes.number,
};

const something = (props) => ((props.props2 > 0 & props.prop1 === props.props3) ?
  t('translation/abc')
  : t('translation/def'));
```

why does the component throw lint error `PropType is defined but prop is never used` for all three props `prop1, prop2, prop3`?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `something.propTypes = { /** rest of propTypes **/ }` and should be after the stateless component ? It's doesn't seem to be using the propTypes that you have declared.

Answer (score 7):

This should fix your problem, let's de-structure your props and then assign propTypes to your stateless component.

```js
const something = ({prop1, prop2, prop3}) => ((props2 > 0 & prop1 === props3) 
  ? t('translation/abc')
  : t('translation/def'));
  
something.propTypes = {
  prop1: PropTypes.string,
  prop2: PropTypes.string,
  prop3: PropTypes.number,
};
```

Comment: Thanks. what happens if there are multiple components say something2, something3 also using the same props?

Comment: @User7354632781 You could always define them in a file and import them but I would honestly start making this component as re-usable as possible to the state where that shouldn't technically happen :)

Answer (score 0):

You are never assigning the propTypes constant to your function, so the props will not be validated against.

If you do

```
something.propTypes = propTypes;
```

the linter should accept your code.