# PropType is defined but prop is never used

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Why am i getting the lint errors `PropType is defined but prop is never used` for all props in the sample code below:

```
const propTypes = {
  prop1: PropTypes.string,
  prop2: PropTypes.string,
  prop3: PropTypes.number,
  prop4: PropTypes.string,
  prop5: PropTypes.number,
};

const userDetails = (props) => ((props.props2 > 0 & props.prop1 === props.props3) ?
  t('translation/abc')
  : t('translation/def'));

const userDetails2 = (props) => ((props.props1 > 0 & props.prop4 === props.props5) ?
  t('translation/ted')
  : t('translation/sted'));
```

Comment: you are actually using only one prop named - `props`. try destructuring: `const userDetails = ({prop1, prop2, prop3}) => ...`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PropType is defined but prop is never used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45527114/proptype-is-defined-but-prop-is-never-used) ... you've already asked this question.

Comment: You're using `props3` and `props5` instead of `prop3` and `prop5`, as defined in the propTypes.

Comment: It's a duplicate question by the same user as indicated by @BugHunterUK

Answer (score -1):

You're not assigning the defined `propTypes` object to your component's instance.

Consider this as a possible solution:

```
const propTypes = {
  prop1: PropTypes.string,
  prop2: PropTypes.string,
  prop3: PropTypes.number,
  prop4: PropTypes.string,
  prop5: PropTypes.number,
};
```

`userDetails.propTypes = propTypes;`

`userDetails2.propTypes = propTypes;`

Comment: sorry i missed to add that but i am doing that